# how to run node.js server when button clicked in react native

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, server

I have a node.js server file for sending push notification.(file name: server.js)
It's working successfully when i write "node server.js" in terminal.
But i dont want to run node.js server like this manually.

I want to run server when button clicked in react native. I tried [this document](https://code.janeasystems.com/nodejs-mobile/getting-started-react-native) but it is not supported on Windows10.
 How can i do that ?

**server.js**

```
const fcm = require('fcm-notification');
const FCM = new fcm('./bildirim8-4090c-firebase.json');
const token =
  'exe-079BQlU:APA91bEI0UFim_Sl4G8mZbfbQ84obrkaXQ47bUlmx_Po5ntkh5hp1BbiNSP_lh28cmUEvUaW5VSe765_yRSVuFyPv5wqgFhh0Jat-Lj3kGZGB-I37lCvg8Ab3q9TRNdOpPBiolS10tmJ';

var message = {
  data: {
    //This is only optional, you can send any data
    score: '850',
    time: '2:45',
  },
  notification: {
    title: 'inside node.js server',
    body: 'message sent!',
  },
  token: token,
};

FCM.send(message, function(err, response) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('error found', err);
  } else {
    console.log('response here', response);
  }
});
```

Comment: You'll need a server that listens to your react app requests that will start a server...

Comment: So,  i need to learn that how to send request to nodejs server. Right?

Answer (score 0):

Your button needs to send a request to the backend. The response is the one to start the server

Comment: Can you explain that how can i send a request to nodejs server briefly pls.

Comment: There are many ways to send requests, but you should read this https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network